# Eval for security concerns?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I found documentation speaking about "Eval is evil", I understood it has performances issues, even MSDN state it:

> Because this method performs late-bound evaluation, using reflection
>   at run time, it can cause performance to noticeably slow compared to
>   standard ASP.NET data-binding syntax - MSDN

Out of the performance issue and considering the following code:

```
<%# Eval("MyDataFieldFromDataBase") %>
```

Can something be done to prevent the field to be interpreted in a dangerous way (to prevent code injection) ?

Comment: You haven't made clear what you mean by "hack".

Comment: making the eval do anything else than displaying the value of `Foo.MyDataFieldFromDatabase`.

Comment: Why? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Ok let me add some context to my question i will make it a bit clearer tell me if it raise other question

Comment: I am trying to find argument to prouve that we should not over use eval in our asp page.

Comment: @PierreLebon Why you are proving that? It is perfectly fine to use one and there is any alternative when you want late binding?

Comment: @PierreLebon I believe you should stop using Eval, but it's not really because of security. It's because it promotes magic strings. If you have a strongly typed GridView you can get much cleaner access to your data. See [this article](https://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/asp-net-4-5-web-forms-features-strongly-typed-data-controls). No need to cast objects, no magic strings.

Comment: I don't know why you assume that I was using Eval, but its ok. Your linked article was great didn't know that <%#:   %> existed (i had a hard time googl-ing it).Btw I do believe that slowing a application is the worst thing about Eval. Having a slow page generation can mean a lot of money on great scale. That should have been enought to make ppl stop using Eval. but yeah i want to have information about the security issue of Eval.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are talking about some different Eval, not ASP.NET's one. Eval in aspx is just a [method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acxb7xys%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), it is as harmful as any other methods.

One potential problem with it is that Eval returns an object, so you can get invalid cast exception if you code did not expect this particular type. Thus you have no type safety using Eval on the page.

Another thing is that Eval does not do any kind of escaping, so if you have potentially dangerous content in your DB, it will be returned as is by Eval. But this is not Eval-specific problem, you just have to make sure you sanitize all user input, Eval has nothing to do with it.

Other than that ASP.NET's Eval is completely harmless.

Comment: Yes , you are right I was talking about Aspx. But i tag asp.net i will correct that , you can edit your post to reflect that. And I was wrong and eval are evil do not apply to aspx Eval. thats great to know. I was expecting to find something to force the team to stop using it but it's ok. I will  just edit their code.

Comment: Your tag looks fine to me, you were asking about ASP.NET eval. aspx is just the type of the markup page that ASPNET uses. no need for retagging

Comment: Eval itself may not do escaping, but with ASP.NET 4.5 you can use the `<#: Eval("SomeField") %>` syntax to encode any output and prevent insertion of scripts into the client side.

Comment: So witch eval m i using when i do `<# Eval("SomeField") %>` ? Is it the AspNet eval or the databinder Eval, that Andrei is talking about ?